# awk execute same command on different files one by one

Tags: bash, for-loop, sed, awk

Hi I have 30 txt files in a directory which are containing 4 columns.
How can I execute a same command on each file one by one and direct output to different file.

The command I am using is as below but its being applied on all the files and giving single output. All i want is to call each file one by one and direct outputs to a new file.

```
start=$1  
patterns=''  
for i in $(seq -43 -14); do   
patterns="$patterns /cygdrive/c/test/kpi/SIGTRAN_Load_$(exec date '+%Y%m%d' --date="-${i} days ${start}")*"; done  
cat /cygdrive/c/test/kpi/*$patterns | sed -e "s/\t/,/g" -e "s/ /,/g"| awk -F, 'a[$3]<$4{a[$3]=$4} END {for (i in a){print i FS a[i]}}'| sed -e "s/ /0/g"| sort -t, -k1,2> /cygdrive/c/test/kpi/SIGTRAN_Load.csv
```

Comment: wrap your command as a shell and loop it while calling the N files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sth like this

```
for fileName in /path/to/files/foo*.txt
do
  mangleFile "$fileName"
done
```

will mangle a list of files you give via globbing.  If you want to generate the file name patterns as in your example, you can do it like this:

```
for i in $(seq -43 -14)
do
  for fileName in /cygdrive/c/test/kpi/SIGTRAN_Load_"$(exec date '+%Y%m%d' --date="-${i} days ${start}")"*
  do
    mangleFile "$fileName"
  done
done
```

This way the code stays much more readable, even if shorter solutions may exist.

The `mangleFile` of course then will be the `awk` call or whatever you would like to do with each file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following idiom:

```
for file in *
do
    ./your_shell_script_containing_the_above.sh $file > some_unique_id
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a loop on all the matching files:

```
for i in /cygdrive/c/test/kpi/*$patterns; do
   tr '[:space:]\n' ',\n' < "$i" | awk -F, 'a[$3]<$4{a[$3]=$4} END {for (i in a){print i FS a[i]}}'| sed -e "s/ /0/g"| sort -t, -k1,2 > "/cygdrive/c/test/kpi/SIGTRAN_Load-$i.csv"
done
```

PS: I haven't tried much to refactor your piped commands that can probably be shortened too.